# Is there an equivelant for Pascal's readkey; in C or C++?

Tags: c++, c, console, pascal, console.readkey

I am looking for a Console function that waits for the user to press a key. I want it to be like Pascal's readkey; as in a Console Only solution. No GUI library / Graphics Library / Windowing Library / WinApi Calls (Windows). It should be cross-platform and (preferably) part of the C std library or C++ Class Library. So is there any such function / class method etc. ?

Comment: http://www.cprogramming.com/fod/kbhit.html

Comment: Writing multi-language source files is difficult. I suggest you keep each source file in only a single, distinct language

Comment: @pmg I don't think that's what his intention was.

Comment: @Paul: the question is tagged both `C` and `C++`. What I mean is for the OP to study the answers and maintain the `C` solution in its own source file and the `C++` in another source file. If I misunderstood the question and what the OP wants is a single solution that works both in `C` and `C++` I suspect he won't get many answers :-)

Comment: @pmg Sorry I guess I was the one who misunderstood your comment. :)

Comment: Standard C++ has no such solution, but then again. Standard Pascal doesn't have `readkey` either.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The C Standard library has no notion of a "keyboard buffer". input/output is mostly line-based (triggered when ENTER is pressed).

You have a few options:

- use an external library like [ncurses](http://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/ncurses.html)
- change the terminal buffering strategy with [`setvbuf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/setvbuf.html) and use [`fgetc()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fgetc.html) (and wait for ENTER if you didn't change the buffering strategy)

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know there is no portable solution for your item. In windows, you can use the header `<conio.h>` which has a function called `getch()` for getting a char directly from the console. If you are in Linux, then you can use the library [ncurses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses).

Comment: So as you are saying that `getch()` isn't portable across other platforms. So how does `getch()` function behaves if I'm running my C program on Linux/unix. I believe `<conio.h>` header file is part of C standard library which will be available across other platforms too or that is an incorrect assumption?

Comment: @RBT `conio.h` is not a part of the standard C. It is not available in *nix. Better follow this thread: [Where is the <conio.h> header file on Linux? Why can't I find <conio.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8792317)

Answer (score 1):

If you're in a Windws run-time environment, you can use the non-standard C function kbhit( ). And there's a C-language Linux equivalent for Windows `kbhit( )`. The function does just what you want: it will tell you if a keyboard character has been typed without reading the character; or, alternatively, will read and deliver to you one character iff one has been typed. You can find it over here:

http://pwilson.net/sample.html

Scroll down to the paragraph headed "Single-character keyboard input for Linux and Unix"

HTH

Answer (score 0):

Considered [_getch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/078sfkak%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) ?

Answer (score 0):

Simple:

```
getchar();
```

Literally the equivalent for `readkey()` in C#.

Comment: `getchar()` requires the user to press ENTER key. I don't think that OP wanted that.