# Where is the <conio.h> header file on Linux? Why can't I find <conio.h>?

Tags: c, linux, gcc, header-files

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to implement getch() function of C in Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3276546/how-to-implement-getch-function-of-c-in-linux)

What is the equivalent `Linux` version of the `conio.h` header file from MS-DOS?

Is there a way to replace its functionality? *e.g. `getch()`*

> I'm using `gcc` and the text editor `Geany` to compile `C` code.

Comment: You can't find it because it's a DOS header!

Comment: @DavidHeffernan  So does that mean we don't need conio.h in linux?

Comment: @Vicrobot It doesn't exist on Linux, ergo you don't need it

Answer (score 125, accepted):

`conio.h` is a C header file used with old MS-DOS compilers to create text user interfaces. Compilers that target other operating systems, such as Linux-based, 32-bit Windows and OS/2, provide equivalent functionality through other header files and libraries.

The `#include <curses.h>` will give you almost all of the functionality provided by `conio.h`.

"ncurses" needs to be installed in the first place.

If you use the Apt package manager:

```
sudo apt-get install libncurses5-dev libncursesw5-dev
```

If you use `rpm`:

```
sudo yum install ncurses-devel ncurses
```

For `getch`, take a look at the ["NCURSES Programming HOWTO"](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/scanw.html#GETCHCLASS) article.

Comment: I am getting error 'fatal error: curses.h: No such file or directory'
what should i do ?

Comment: @kanojesumit That means that a curses library is not installed. It is not a standard library. You will need to find it online (for instance Ncurses is a free GPL implementation).

Comment: Programs that use `curses` or `ncurses` normally take over the entire (text) screen, which may or may not be what you want.

Comment: Even i am getting error                                                                                                                                                                                                       permutation.c:2:19: fatal error: curses.h: No such file or directory
 #include<curses.h>
                   ^
compilation terminated.

Comment: Everyone says curses but the issue with curses is that it MUST take over your console environment.

If you already have a console program, you need to rewrite the whole thing in curses to be consistant, as curses manages its own screen. Why can't we just port conio?

Answer (score 26):

The original **conio.h** was implemented by Borland, so its not a part of the C Standard Library nor is defined by POSIX.

[But here is an implementation for Linux](http://sourceforge.net/projects/linux-conioh/) that uses ncurses to do the job.

Answer (score 8):

That is because it does not exist, since it is bounded to Windows.

Use the standard functions from `<stdio.h>` instead, such as getc

The suggested ncurses library is good if you want to write console-based GUIs, but I don't think it is what you want.

Comment: Didn't work for me

Comment: @Scott What did not work for you? Were you unable to `#include <stdio.h>`?

Answer (score 7):

A popular Linux library which has similar functionality would be [ncurses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses).