# How to print odd numbers ( 1 -> 10) by do - while

Tags: c, loops, while-loop, numbers

How to print odd numbers ( 1 -> 10) by do - while?

My code: http://codepad.org/yS6DNq8Y

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
 int i;
void Dayso()
{

    do 
    {
        i = 1
        i++;
        if ( i % 2 == 0 )
        {
            continue;
        }
        printf ("\n%d",i);

    }while (i <= 10 );

}

int main()
{
    Dayso ();
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

and the output:

```
Line 18: error: conio.h: No such file or directory
In function 'Dayso':
Line 10: error: expected ';' before 'i'
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: The error messages are way clear: start adding a `;` at the end of row 9. About the error `Line 18: error: conio.h: No such file or directory`, [this might help you]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8792317/why-cant-i-find-conio-h-on-linux).

Comment: What is the very first thing done in the loop body (and thus done every loop)? Why (is this a problem)?

Comment: Move `i=1` to outer scope and add semicolon to it.

Answer (score 3):

Compile errors:

1. There is no `conio.h` header file in Linux machines. You can remove `getch()` function in this program.
2. You are missing semicolon in line 9.

Logic errors:

1. You are assigning 1 to `i` variable (9 line) on every do while iteration so you have just created infinite cycle. Move assignment to 1 outside the loop.
2. You are missing 1 from ods and 11 gets printed in current implementation.

Corrected solution:
http://ideone.com/IB3200

```
#include <stdio.h>

void Dayso()
{
    int i = 1;
    do 
    {
        if ( i % 2 != 0 ) {
            printf ("\n%d",i);
        }

        i++;
    } while (i <= 10 );

}

int main()
{
    Dayso ();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

int a = 2;

```
    do {
        System.out.println(a);
            a++;
        if (a%2==0);
        a++;
    }

    while (a <= 20);
    }
}
```

// for printing even number using do-while loop in java

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: The edit queue is full so I cant fix the obvious errors: starting at ` a =2` and continuing to `a <= 20` means you miss 1 and get 11/13/15/17/19 - so you haven't answered the question... likewise, the question is tagged `C` not java.