# Gotoxy() in xcode

Tags: xcode, macos, move, conio

I've been looking around for a way to use the function gotoxy() in xcode. But as it is connected to the conio.h library (which is not supported in xcode) I cant get it to work. Can anybody please tell me how to get around this problem? I've googled, asked around - but have not found anything that works...

Comment: Use ncurses. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8792317/why-cant-i-find-conio-h-on-linux

Comment: Tried it, can't get it to work. But i solved it by making my own "gotoexy". Thanks tho!