# C++ - Pause program until a certain key is pressed

Tags: c++

Is there a function that makes a command prompt program wait like `system("pause")`, and continues running only after accepting a certain key?

Comment: you might want to take a look at [ncurses](https://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/)

Comment: Do you mean like stepping through code one line at a time?

Comment: Not in the C++ Standard Library.

Comment: Also are you talking about a "normal" command line program or something platform specific or ...? And what is the program supposed to do while waiting? absolutely nothing (in which case you could just use blocking IO)?

Comment: To clarify, I want it to work like system("pause"), except that it only accepts a certain key. I'll edit the question.

Comment: Which os are you using..i guess system pause doesn't work on Linux does it?

Answer (score 2):

If you're waiting for a newline character, there's an easy and portable way to do that. Just use `getline`.

If you want to receive other characters without receiving a newline first, then things are less portable. In Unix systems, you'll need to set your terminal to "raw mode". As George's comment mentions, ncurses is an easy way to do this, plus it provides handy functions for drawing things to a specific place in the terminal, receiving arbitrary keys, etc.

On Windows, you'll need to use its [console interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/ms682010.aspx). This is, of course, not usable outside of Windows.

As Neil Butterworth comments, there's also a version of curses that works for Windows, called PDCurses. If you need to write software that works for both Unix and Windows, that's a good option to pursue.

Answer (score 0):

If getline and ncurses don't work for you there is always conio.h and getch().  There are some problems with this as explained in this answer [Why can't I find <conio.h> on Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8792317/why-cant-i-find-conio-h-on-linux)

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

If you're on Windows, you can use kbhit() which is part of the Microsoft run-time library. If you're on Linux, you can implement kbhit thus

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int kbhit(void)
{
  struct termios oldt, newt;
  int ch;
  int oldf;

  tcgetattr(STDIN_FILENO, &oldt);
  newt = oldt;
  newt.c_lflag &= ~(ICANON | ECHO);
  tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &newt);
  oldf = fcntl(STDIN_FILENO, F_GETFL, 0);
  fcntl(STDIN_FILENO, F_SETFL, oldf | O_NONBLOCK);

  ch = getchar();

  tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &oldt);
  fcntl(STDIN_FILENO, F_SETFL, oldf);

  if(ch != EOF)
  {
    ungetc(ch, stdin);
    return 1;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Compiling steps :

```
 gcc -o kbhit kbhit.c
```

When run with

```
 ./kbhit
```

It prompts you for a keypress, and exits when you hit a key (not limited to Enter or printable keys).

(Got over internet - you can modify code and use specific ch value like \n for Enter key)