# How to include or link ncurses/ curses library in Codeblocks 13.12 in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, codeblocks

Hope you are doing great!

I am using codeblocks 13.12 in my Elementary OS (Loki) which is based on ubuntu 16.04. Recently , I tried to use getch(), getche() function in my C-language coding and to do that i installed ncurses library in my system. When i try to build code, I get two error messages-

1. Undefined reference to 'stdscr'
2. Undefined reference to 'wgetch'

Here is my sample code:

```
#include'stdio.h'
#include'ncurses.h'
int main(){
    char ch;
    printf("Enter a character: ");
    ch=getch();
    printf("\nIts ASCII is : %d .",ch);
    return 0;
}
```

What is the solution?
I know i have to link the library to my source code file in command line.

Here is my command line execution :
`gcc -o example_3_1_1test1 example_3_1_1.c -lncurses`

complies without error

```
Enter a character: 
Its ASCII is : -1
```

which is wrong. Because my program don't take input from keyboard and   automatically returns -1.

I want to build/complile my code from codeblocks automatically. So, how can i link ncurses library in codeblocks 13.12?

Thanks in advance.

Nazmul

Comment: Maybe this should be moved to askubuntu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**setting** > **complier** > **search directories**

Just click on add

[image]

I linked the `boost` library

[image]

**and**

[image]

**and**
put your `-lncurses` here as I put `-pthread` and `std=c11`

[image]

Comment: Thanks for quick response.

I followed your instruction like this- https://i.stack.imgur.com/JDmNC.png

and https://i.stack.imgur.com/l5HQJ.png

Still I find errors - Undefined reference to 'stdscr' Undefined reference to 'wgetch'

Any idea why?

Comment: @nazmulwanted You said: *I know i have to link the library to my source code file in command line* what **command** did you try? you should find the location of the file

Comment: @nazmulwanted May help you [How do I link to a library with Code::Blocks?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5862757/how-do-i-link-to-a-library-with-codeblocks)

Comment: here is my main code- <code>#include<stdio.h>
#include<ncurses.h>
int main(){
    char ch;

    printf("Enter a character: ");
    ch=getch();

    printf("\nIts ASCII is : %d .",ch);

    return 0;
}</code>
and in command line i wrote this 
<code>gcc -o example_3_1_1test1 example_3_1_1.c -lncurses</code>
which complies fine but output wrong.
output is -
'code'Enter a character: 
Its ASCII is : -1 'code'
but also in codeblocks shows mentioned error.

Comment: @nazmulwanted Oh no! put your code in your question not here! and see that like that I comment you

Comment: ops! sorry!  i am a newbie here. Sorry again.

Comment: @nazmulwanted Do not worry. **Just** edit your question and put your code in. if you made it messy I would fix it :)

Comment: edited my question. please check. thanks for your help.

Comment: @nazmulwanted/ almost I find it you need to put `-lncurses`  in the compiler

Comment: i have to put -lncurses in which tab or option in the compiler settings?

Comment: @nazmulwanted See the new picture that I have put or follow **setting** and tab 2 **other complier option**

Comment: Thanks a lot! It Works! Still small problem- getch() function is not working the  way i wanted... if you check my code you will understand. My program supposed to take input from my keyboard and show ASCII value of it and still getting -1. Which is wrong. Any idea?

Comment: @nazmulwanted I am not familiar with `ncurses.h` but why do not you use `scanf` function for reading a char?  like: `scanf( &ch );`

Comment: i was just experimenting my code. I know about scanf, but i needed getch/getche function  feature which takes character input and then my program goes immediately to next instruction without pressing enter key. for that I used conio.h in windows machine. But in linux gcc doest not provide conio.h. Btw Thanks a lot. You really helped me. :)

Comment: @nazmulwanted May help you [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8792317/why-cant-i-find-conio-h-on-linux) ------- or this [link](https://github.com/nowres/conio-for-linux)