# How do install ncurses for Deepin Linux gcc?

Tags: c++, c, linux

I currently use Atom text editor on [deepin Linux distribution](https://www.deepin.org). I am also okay if you can tell me how to install `conio.h`.

Comment: `conio.h` is MS-DOS programming garbage. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8792317/why-cant-i-find-conio-h-on-linux)

Comment: Ah, since the distro is Debian based, I guess it is a full duplicate then