# C++ Mac | Conio alternative

Tags: c++, command-line-interface, conio

I've just learnt C++ in the last few months and want to start making some CLI games, like the old school Snake, Frogger, Pong, etc... I've found some sources where people use the conio header. I've researched and have found this isn't compatible with Mac..

Does conio work on Debian? I use mint.
Also, is there an alternative to conio for mac?

Comment: Worth a read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8792317/why-cant-i-find-conio-h-on-linux
Using ncurses is probably the way to go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<conio.h>` is a DOS header, and thus it doesn't work on Mac or on Debian. There are many libraries you can use instead, with varying degrees of portability; as a commentor suggested, [`ncurses`](https://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/) might be a good choice, or you can look for similar alternatives online.

Comment: Thanks for that, I'll do more research