# Conio.h not found in CLion

Tags: c, ide, clion

I'm new to CLion and I'm using it on Ubuntu 18.04. I imported an existing project and when I build it, the following message appears:

```
conio.h: No such file or directory
 #include <conio.h>
```

I thought that conio.h was a library included in most Ubuntu distributions.If not, how do I install it or how can I add the dependencies to the project?

Edit: For clarify, I didn't touched anything on the project settings or dependencies yet.

Comment: There is a `conio` library as part of the Windows C suites if that is where your project came from. But it is OS-specific. Similar functionality might be found in `termios` or `ncurses` libraries for Linux.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where is the <conio.h> header file on Linux? Why can't I find <conio.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8792317/where-is-the-conio-h-header-file-on-linux-why-cant-i-find-conio-h)

Answer (score 2):

`#include <conio.h>` it's a Windows library.

When you work in Linux, you may use `#include <curses.h>`
But it's not a standard library!