# why does this error occur: 'conio.h' file not found

Tags: c

i'm new to C programing and i was testing some code when i compiled it this error came up:

```
fatal error: 'conio.h' file not found #include <conio.h>
```

this was on the top of the code i was testing:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
...
```

i searched about this error but i only found answers related to windows and ubuntu

i'm running mac os

Comment: The header conio.h is not a standard C header. Do not use it.

Comment: Looks like another dup of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8792317/1707353).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where is the <conio.h> header file on Linux? Why can't I find <conio.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8792317/where-is-the-conio-h-header-file-on-linux-why-cant-i-find-conio-h)

Comment: Here are a couple versions: https://github.com/zoelabbb/conio.h and https://github.com/thradams/conio

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`conio.h` is not a standard library header, and the functions it declares are not standard library functions - it's specific to an *ancient* implementation that isn't used much anymore.  If the code you're trying to build uses `conio` routines like `getch()`, then it won't build on a Mac.

Comment: is there an alternative for mac, or is this program is entirely incompatible with Mac?

Comment: @MakeTheErrorDie: There really isn't a `conio` equivalent for MacOS.  As for whether the program is *entirely* incompatible, I can't say without seeing the code.  On the implementation that provided it, it was common to launch programs from within the IDE - it would open a new terminal window in which the program would run.  As soon as the program exited, the window would close.  A lot of intro programs put `getch()` as the last statement so the program wouldn't exit until you pressed a key.

Comment: @MakeTheErrorDie: It's possible that the only thing you need to do is remove the `#include <conio.h>` and any `getch()` statements and your code will build and run correctly.  It's also possible that it makes more use of `conio` than that - without seeing the code I can't really say.

Comment: removing getch() and # include <conio.h> worked :)

Comment: This does not solve the OPs problem.

Comment: @Johan: Yes it did -- see the OP's comment immediately before yours.

Answer (score 1):

It depends of what compiler are you using.
Conio.h is mostly header for MS-DOS compiler, so it can be unavailable in some others packages.
If you tried to use getch() as tool to stop console from closing after execution, simply replace it with scanf():

```
int a;
scanf("%d", &a);
```

Console will close after pressing Enter

Comment: the guy said C not C++

Comment: @Holeryn oops, my bad

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same situation. My xcode suggested #include <curses.h> instead. I changed accordingly, now it builds.

Answer (score 0):

The entire form of conio.h is "Console Input & Output." In C programming, the console input and output function is provided by the header file conio.h. Since we learned that the conio.h file has console input/output functions, the GCC compiler does not support it. Thus, we will talk about a few key features that are utilized to hold the screen, clean the screen, and adjust the text's backdrop color. "conio.h" Don't use it. A header file was discovered in Turbo C/C++, which utilizes a 16-bit compiler. However, it isn't available in GCC, thus none of the functions—such as clrscr(), getch(), gets, and cgets—will work with it.

Answer (score -1):

See here Conio is dead already do not use my friend I have noticed many YouTubers in initial coding use getch() to make your code wait for you to press a key and when pressed it is done but now conio isn't even a part of c/c++ it works in MS-DOS based compiler and turbo-c++ but most of the turbo c++ code turns out erroneous as they use old c/++ syntax that is deprecated a long back in the history of development in c/c++.

```
    #include <conio.h>
```

Suggestion : Remove These lines and voila it works
Happy Coding!

Answer (score -1):

"use this line in main function
then we can use conio file
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])"

Comment: How would this allow using a file that does not exist?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).