# How do I detect if a key is being held down in C++?

Tags: c++, linux

How do I detect if a key is being held down in C++? An example of how I'd like to use it:

```cpp
while (varOne == 0) {
    if ('A' Key Pressing Code Detection Magic Goes Here) {
        std::cout << "The 'A' key has been pressed.";
        varOne = 2;
    }
}
```

I have found a few articles saying to use the `conio.h` library, however a bunch of people advise against using it. Should I use `conio.h`? Or is there some other method? (Not sure if it matters, but I'm using VS Code on Linux.)

Comment: ***Should I use conio.h?*** On linux? Related: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8792317/where-is-the-conio-h-header-file-on-linux-why-cant-i-find-conio-h](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8792317/where-is-the-conio-h-header-file-on-linux-why-cant-i-find-conio-h)

Comment: What 'key' do you use? if it is a simple character you can use getchar(). It looks like you want the 'A' key, so getchar() will do the job.

Comment: Standard C++ has no concept of "keyboards", so all questions like this are implementation- and OS-dependent.  It definitely matters that you are using Linux, and so you should check the articles you read that they are also meant for Linux.  `conio.h` is an ancient header from MS-DOS.

Answer (score 3):

Since your on linux, you might want to look for a `curses` library. Possible helpful info for `ncurses` (the modern C++ `curses` library):

https://www.linuxjournal.com/content/getting-started-ncurses,

https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/,

https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-install-ncurses-library-headers-on-debian-ubuntu-centos-fedora/.

I'm not a real expert on `linux`, but this may help.

The accepted answer here : [Where is the <conio.h> header file on Linux? Why can't I find <conio.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8792317/where-is-the-conio-h-header-file-on-linux-why-cant-i-find-conio-h) explains a bit on `conio.h` and `ncurses`.